# Find spectrum of integral operator in L2

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, spectral-theory, integral-operators

Please help me find the spectrum of operator $A$, I do not speak English well. In Russian forums I did not find the answer.

Find spectrum of integral operator in $L_2$($R$):
$$ (Ax)(t) = \int\limits_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \dfrac{x(s)ds}{1+(t-s)^2}\ $$
This is Fredholm integral operator (first type)
$$K(t,s) = \dfrac{1}{1+(t-s)^2}$$
Eigenvalues ​​are found from the condition $Ax=\lambda x$

The spectrum will consist of $0$ and its own conceptions

Comment: Your operator is unitary equivalent to the operator of multiplication by some function. And this unitary equivalence carries out the Fourier transform. You should know everything about the spectrum of the operator of multiplication by a function. It remains to apply the Fourier transform and understand what kind of operator it is. If you know how the Fourier transform affects the convolution of functions, then everything is quite simple.

Comment: Unfortunately I don’t know how the Fourier transform is applied, I looked that others solved such operators somehow through differentiation

Comment: Your operator is a convolution type operator. Let $F$ be the Fourier operator, then $FAx=\sqrt{2\pi}F(1/(1+t^2))F(x)=TF(x)$. So $A$ is unitary equivalent to $Tx(\tau)=\sqrt{2\pi}F(1/(1+t^2))x(\tau)$. It's remain to calculate $F(1/(1+t^2))$ and say that the spectrum of $A$ is the set of values of $F(1/(1+t^2))$. I'm afraid there is no other solution.

Comment: I will try to solve, thanks. I’ll say later whether it turned out or not

Comment: I found the final Fourier transform using the residue theorem, how can I find the spectrum now? $\pi e^{-\omega}$

Comment: There module $\pi e^{-|\omega|}$

Comment: Where does the $2\pi$ comes from in your Fourier transform @Smipe